# How to put plural parameters into url with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to build a website with a plural levels in the url. When it gets deeper,I find it difficult to get the parameters in the url.For example, www.example.com/level1/level2, I can get plural parameters level2(plural pages) because I know level1,but as it keeps going like level1/level2/level3,since parameter level2 is unknown value,how should I get level3? Because based on what I'm thinking, there are level4 and level5, at last, should the route file look like Route::get('/{parameter1}/{parameter2}/{parameter3}/{parameter4}','Controller@func')?
Any reply will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
{{ url('func', ['level1' => 'val1', 'level2' => 'val2', 'level3' => 'val3']) }} // your link

Route::get('/func', 'YourController@func');
```

your action method

```
public function func(Request $request){
  $level3 = $request->get('level3');
}
```